# The Definitive Guide to Extending Twig in Craft CMS

Tags: plugin-development, templating, twigextension

So Craft's implementation of Twig is already very powerful and suitable to most common tasks. The Craft Docs already provide a great intro into using Twig and the handy extensions provided by Craft:

- [Craft Templating Overview](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating-overview)
- [Craft Twig Primer](https://craftcms.com/docs/twig-primer)
- [Craft Full Templating Reference](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating)

**But what about when you need to go further and build in some sweet custom functionality?**

This question serves to be a starting point that summarises all the different ways to extend Twig with custom functionality, including:

- Filters, functions, objects, macros and statements – when to use which
- Creating a custom Twig filter
- Accessing variables and functions in a plugin
- Creating a custom global function
- Creating a custom global object
- Creating a custom statement (or "logic tag")
- Creating a custom operator
- Calling a plugin service class from Twig
- Making custom database calls from Twig
- Post-processing HTML after Twig has finished rendering
- Changing Twig settings

Answer (score 14):

> *To encourage input, this is a community wiki post. Any user with at least 100 reputation points may contribute.*

## Functions, filters, objects, macros and statements – when to use which

A **function** is one of the simplest constructs in Twig – it takes one or more inputs and returns a single output:

```
{{ round(42.9) }} will output 43
```

These are best used for simple, commonly used operations that generate or transform data, such as a Lorem-Ipsum generator: `{{ loremIpsum(50) }}`. But note that functions are often better grouped into an object to prevent name collisions (see below).

A **filter** is almost identical to a function, except that it offers a different syntax, which can be more readable when chaining several filters together (they read in progressive order):

```
{{ 1000000 | number }} will output 1,000,000
{{ 1000000 | number(false) }} will output 1000000
{{ 'ABC' | lower | replace('c', 'd') }} will output abd
```

It also provides an easy way to wrap around a larger block of text:

```
{% filter upper %}
    This text becomes uppercase
{% endfilter %}
```

Note that you can also do this with a function, but it requires an additional line:

```
{% set myText %}
    A quick brown fox
{% endset %}
{{ filterCurseWords(myText) }}
```

Use a filter when:

- It might be necessary to place it in a chain along with other filters
- It might be necessary to place around larger blocks of text/content

A **global variable** is one accessible to all templates in your project automatically:

```
<h1>{{ siteName }}</h1>
```

A **global object** is also accessible to all templates in your project, but can contain variables, functions or both:

```
{{ currentUser.friendlyName }}
{{ currentUser.can('accessCp') }}
```

Objects provide a good way to neatly group variables and functions and prevent collisions.

A Twig **statement** (sometimes called a "logic tag") is used to designate the flow of logic and may only execute the content inside based on certain circumstances.

```
{% cache %}
    {% for block in entry.myMatrixField %}
        <p>{{ block.text }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endcache %}
```

Note that caching would not work as a filter, because the content inside a filter is always executed *prior* to being passed into the filter. By implementing the cache tag as a *statement*, it is able to only execute the content inside when appropriate.

Finally, it's worth mentioning **macros**. They assist with reusing snippets of content or HTML in multiple places. Mijingo has written a [great tutorial](https://mijingo.com/blog/using-macros-in-twig-and-craft) that explains macros in Craft.

```
{% import "forms.html" as forms %}
{{ forms.input('username') }}
```

Note, however, that the functionality of macros can sometimes be replicated via a simple include, with less code and more clarity:

```
{% include 'mySnippet' with { enabled: true } %}
```

---

## Creating a custom Twig filter

```
{{ myVariable | myFilter }}
```

*More content to come here. Feel free to contribute some instructions if you're able.*

---

## Accessing a plugin's variables and functions

```
{{ craft.myPlugin.myVariable }}
{{ craft.myPlugin.myFunction() }}
```

*More content to come here. Feel free to contribute some instructions if you're able.*

---

## Creating a custom global function

```
{{ customFunction() }}
```

*More content to come here. Feel free to contribute some instructions if you're able.*

---

## Creating a custom global object

```
{{ browser.version }}
{{ browser.isMobile() }}
```

*More content to come here. Feel free to contribute some instructions if you're able.*

---

## Creating a custom statement (logic tag)

```
{% devOnly %}
    ...output some debugging info here...
{% endDevOnly %}
```

Refer to http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/advanced.html#tags

*More content to come here. Feel free to contribute some instructions if you're able.*

Be aware that sometimes the functionality can be achieved by creating a filter instead of a statement:

```
{% filter uppercase %}
    A quick brown fox
{% endfilter %}
```

However the benefit of a statement is that the code inside is not run unless the statement permits it, whereas in a filter the code is always run, and then later sent to the filter.

---

## Creating a custom operator

```
{{ ! true }}
```

Refer to http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/advanced.html#operators

*More content to come here. Feel free to contribute some instructions if you're able.*

---

## Calling a plugin service class from Twig

Under normal circumstances, Twig templates only have access to a plugins *Variable Classes* and not their *Service Classes*. But using a simple PHP trick, you can pass all calls on transparently:

*Twig > Variable Class > Service Class*

```
// craft/plugins/YourPlugin/variables/YourPluginVariable.php
class YourPluginVariable
{
    /** 
     * If function is not found in this class, go find it in service class
     */
    function __call($method, $arguments) {
        return call_user_func_array(array(craft()->YourPlugin_YourService, $method), $arguments);
    }   
}
```

Be sure to rename `YourPlugin` and `YourService` to reflect the names of your plugin and service class.

---

## Making custom database calls from Twig

```
{{ craft.myPlugin.fetchUserCount() }}
```

Firstly this requires a custom plugin.

In Craft, database calls need to be made via a service class, however because you can only access *variable classes* from Twig, you need to pass one to the other. (See the point above for a clean way to transparently pass calls from a variable class to a service class.)

Twig > Variable Class > Service Class > Database Query

*More content to come here. Feel free to contribute some instructions if you're able.*

---

## Post-processing HTML after Twig has finished rendering

*More content to come here. Feel free to contribute some instructions if you're able.*

---

## Changing Twig settings

*More content to come here. Feel free to contribute some instructions if you're able.*